# Trying to set up a deployment package for silent uninstall of Notepad++ and installation of a new version

Tags: batch-file, deployment, cmd, notepad++, silent-installer

All of the below on Windows 7 Machines and regarding Notepad++ installation / uninstallation:

**Uninstaller**

When I try to uninstall using the command

`if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\uninstall.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\uninstall.exe" /S`

there are some files left in the Notepad++ file afterward.  Notepad++'s uninstaller, when run manually, prompts halfway through the uninstall asking "Do you want to keep your custom settings" and I'm thinking that the command may be choosing to answer this "Yes" by default.  I'm wondering if there's an easy way to have it choose "No" here instead.  If not, I can probably just delete the folder.

**Installer**

I'm running the installation using the 32 bit default .exe file from Notepad++ in a deployment package compiled in Lansweeper.  What I'm noticing is that presently, the package executed the CMD uninstall command, but stops short of installing the new version.  For reference, I've been using an installed 7.3.2 and the installer for 7.3.3 to test, so that it should uninstall the 7.3.2 and install 7.3.3 by the end of the package.

I'm wondering if the fact that there are a number of options in the Notepad++ installer could be the culprit here.  If it is better to install via command line or to include some sort of configuration file I'm fine with either option, just not especially well-versed in doing them.

Notepad++ Installer requests the following during installation:

1. Select a language - should choose English
2. Choose Components - want to be able to customize selection of localization / auto complete / themes / context menu / plugins / auto update according to our requirements
3. Choose Components - Don't use Appdata, Allow Plugins to be loaded from Appdata, and Create Shortcut on Desktop should all remain unchecked
4. Run Notepad ++ - should be unchecked (checked by default)

All the other components that I can see are straightforward Next / I Agree buttons.

I'm hoping someone may be able to make helpful suggestions here as I've not had any experience with configuring silent installs with specific parameters.  Notepad++ doesn't seem to have its own MSI and I won't use a third party one so some sort of batch or configuration file or flagging options in cmd if possible are the preferable options.

Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide that may be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the silent uninstall option was broken due to the prompt about keeping custom settings. When this was fixed in v7.2 I believe the fix was to leave those files by default, _in the program files location_. As you are deploying a new version of the same program, it would seem a bad decision if you were to also remove your end users customisations. Technically this is a software question and is off topic here in programming.

Comment: Thanks for the information - in your opinion then there should be no problem with leaving the files between installations then?

Apologies for getting the location wrong - is there an easy way to move it?

Comment: I see no reason why you cannot **R**e**M**ove the **DIR**ectory between the Uninstall and new Install.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to update to the latest version. It is quite simple. Run the newest installer again and it will automatically update older versions.

See
[Silent Install Notepad++](https://www.silent-install.net/software/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/7.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the command:

```
start /wait npp.7.2.Installer.x64.exe /S
```

Didn't show any interface during silent installation.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad kicks a secondary process that doesn't finish until success is evaluated.

try:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\uninstall.exe" /S

timeout 5
```